# Continuous piecewise function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that, the function

$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x- 1, when -1 \leqslant x < 1\\ 
ax+b, when \; 1 \leqslant x < 2  \\ 
3x,  when \; 2 \leqslant x < 4
\end{aligned} 
\right. $$

is continuous within its domain $[-1, 4)$.

So i approached this the way i used to in high school by finding the limits of both sides for $1$ and $2$, then solved the system which resulted in $a = 6$ and $b = -6$. I'm not sure, though, if this is how one should solve these at university. Is there some other approach I'm missing here?

Comment: No, you are correct. The same approach should work regardless of whether you are in high school or the university.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you don't need to write it rigorously with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. Whenever the right-hand limit and left-hand limit is equal to value of a function at this very point you could conclude that it is continuous at that point.